# LMS adaptive filter - is it Least mean square or least mean squares?

Tags: lms

It seems both names are used for the same algorithm:

**least mean square** - mainly literature before 1990, for example: *Widrow, Bernard, and Samuel D. Stearns. "Adaptive signal processing prentice-hall." Englewood Cliffs, NJ (1985).*

**least mean squares** - newer papers / popular posts, for example: wikipedia

What is the correct name? Does it matter? Is there a difference I miss?

Comment: I always thought is was the former.  Without plural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According [this](https://www-isl.stanford.edu/%7Ewidrow/papers/j2005thinkingabout.pdf) 2005 Stanford reference, "Thinking about Thinking, the Discovery of the LMS Algorithm", in 1960 the algorithm was baptized *least mean square*.

> I met Ted for the first time on a Friday afternoon in the fall of 1959. [...]
> We didn’t have a name for this algorithm. A year or so later, my Ph.D. students, James S. Koford, gave it the name LMS algorithm for “least mean square,” and the name stuck.